How do you debug a .net project in Docker that has been set up to build without a Dockerfile
I have a simple .net 8 console app that I can build and create a container from using the following command.
dotnet publish /t:PublishContainer
I have it configured to not need a Dockerfile to build with all of the needed information in the csproj file.   I can't however debug the project from Visual Studio in Docker.
Below is everything in the .csproj file that gets me to the point of being able to build and publish to my local docker.
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <IsPublishable>true</IsPublishable>
    <EnableSdkContainerSupport>true</EnableSdkContainerSupport>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ContainerRepository>whack-a-mole</ContainerRepository>
    <ContainerBaseImage>my.com/custom/image:basedon-jammy</ContainerBaseImage>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <EnableSdkContainerDebugging>True</EnableSdkContainerDebugging>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I also added a launchSettings.json file in the Project folder with the following but am still missing something
{
  "profiles": {
    "WhackAMole": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    },
    "WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "distributionName": ""
    },
    "Run in Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker"
    }
  }
}


https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/debugging-dotnet-containers-with-visual-studio-code-docker-tools/

Is there any update? Does the answer below solve your problem?

In VS 17.10 you can enable this with Add->"Docker Support":

Then choose Container Build Type: ".NET SDK":

That said, looking at your project you've already done 90% of what it would do, the only obvious issue is that the launch profile should be:
"Container (.NET SDK)": {
  "commandName": "SdkContainer"
}

